# Failed to open Database Android Java SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("/gregpeck.db", null);

}
```

Obviously this is inside my Main Activity.

I have also added the permission to my Main Activity:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="ie.callanan.dennis.testhw" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
```

The error message I receive is:

```
Failed to open database 'gregpeck.db'.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
```

Comment: Did you try to change the path? You can get the path to your SD card programmatically with `getExternalFilesDir()` or `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` (have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#SavingSharedFiles for more details)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use a `SQLiteOpenHelper`, if you need a private database for your application:

```
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DatabaseName";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE ....";

    public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database,int oldVersion,int newVersion){
        // do whatever is required for the upgrade 
    }
}
```

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141008060218/http://www.perfectapk.com/sqliteopenhelper-example.html) you find a full example. If you want to open a database from SD card, use:

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/db.sqlite" ); 
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(file, null);
Log.d("MyApp", "Successfully opened: "  + db.isOpen());
```

For the first case you don't need any particular permissions. For the second one you do. *Note*: Android 4.3 and 4.4 do restrict the access on the SD card. So it might be that you cannot access the database file at all (see for instance this [article](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/askjack/2014/oct/09/how-can-i-get-android-kitkat-to-work-with-my-sd-cards)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any idea what the cause of the problem is though?

Comment: @John: Sorry, my post was not completed: I guess the problem is either your path (`"/...`) or the fact that Android 4.3/4.4 doesn't allow to access every kind of contents on SD cards. You'll find a lot of information about this in the web.