# SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database

Tags: android, sqlite

My problem is when i select different lenguage from app, and again open app it app gone crash and it show `Failed to open database`.error is persist whenever we select different language  from app. I tried from last two days.I used some answer but they don't work for me.Please any one help me.

**My error is**

```
 E/FA: Opening the local database failed, dropping and recreating it
     E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/<package
     name>/databases/google_app_measurement_local.db'.
```

Comment: try to uninstall the app and run it again

Comment: I tried many times.Same error is showing.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try to Post your code here where actual process take place, if you need to comment to clarify the question, please do so.

Anyway, the possible issue you are facing could be:

- You mistakenly rename the DB File, so check your file existence first
- Did you try to change the path? You can get the external path SD card programmatically with `getExternalFilesDir()` or `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` from your SQLiteOpenHelper Class(if you have one) Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28386425/3970630).
- Or you could refer to [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html) for DB
- Try [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/783073/A-Simple-Android-SQLite-Example), but not recommended since you can copy paste everything from here.

Comment: same error is showing.I think "google_app_measurement_local.db"  this is by default created by firebase .

Comment: Thanks Ric..still i am struggling with problem.